# Do /dev/tty and current /dev/pts/X are the same things?

Tags: tty

Writing file to `/dev/tty` and `/dev/pts/7` in this case results that it is printed in console:

```
$ echo hello > file.txt
$ cp file.txt /dev/tty
hello
$ tty
/dev/pts/7
$ cp file.txt /dev/pts/7
hello
```

Do these two files are synonyms in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they act identically.  `/dev/tty` is a special character device that resembles your "current terminal".  This is for convenience, so that you don't have to look what your actual terminal is when needed but just can open `/dev/tty`, independent whether it's `/dev/pts/5` or `/dev/pty7` or `/dev/tty3`.